# Retrofit "IllegalStateException: Already executed"

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, rx-android, retrofit2

I have a Retrofit network call that id like to run every 5 seconds. My current code:

```
Handler h = new Handler();
int delay = 5000; //milliseconds

h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ApiResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<ApiResponse> response) {
                Log.d("api", "response: " + response.body().getPosition().getLatitude().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

            }
        });
        h.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
}, delay);
```

This runs once, but then throws the following:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already executed.
>           at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.enqueue(OkHttpCall.java:52)
>           at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.enqueue(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:57)
>           at orbyt.project.MyFragment$1.run(MyFragment.java:93)

Whats the issue here?

As a bonus: whats a better way to handle this? Ill be updating a map every update. I was thinking about trying to use Rx but not sure if this is an appropriate use-case, or how to implement it.

Comment: is it possible that your network call is taking longer than 5 seconds, so when the second iteration starts the first iteration has not finished yet? The delay doesn't start when the first iteration ended, but 5 seconds from the time you called the first iteration

Comment: @TooManyEduardos well I know for a fact the first call is completing because Im logging the response, and am in fact getting data.

Comment: but the log just shows you the data received, not the network connection finished. It might still be closing elements within the 5 second window. This is just an idea, but try increasing the delay to like 15 seconds and see if the issue goes away

Comment: @TooManyEduardos changed the delay to 15 seconds, still getting the same error.

Comment: I don't understand what is unclear, here. it tells you what does not work, and why. If in doubt, refer to the doc https://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/ It plainly says `Throws:
    IllegalStateException - when the call has already been executed.` Your call has already been executed, since that's what you want - repeat the call - and the IllegalStateException is thrown. Nothing surprising here.

Comment: call even says `it cannot be executed twice.`

Comment: @njzk2 I had searched for solutions specific to Retrofit as well as checking out the Retrofit issue tracker, but hadn't found anything suggesting why this would be an issue. I figured it couldnt be called twice, as instantiating a new Retrofit `Call` inside the `Runnable` also worked. Jakes solution below solves the issue nicely. Thanks for the links regardless, I didnt check the actual official documentation for `Call`, which would have provided the answer.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

A `Call` can only be used once. [Its documentation](http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html) tells you how to use one multiple times:

> Use `clone()` to make multiple calls with the same parameters to the same webserver; this may be used to implement polling or to retry a failed call.

So use `call.clone().enqueue(..)` for **Asynchornous** and `call.clone().execute()` for **Synchornous** *respectively*  to ensure that you have a fresh, unexecuted `Call` for each request.

Comment: Hi @Jake Wharton, I'm calling same API multiple times using: if( call.isExecuted() ) { call.cancel(); }  call.clone().enqueue(..) , I want to receive response only from last/latest call, but getting response for every call ?

Comment: @Deven that is probably only reliably doable if you limit Ok to a single request at a time `new Retrofit.Builder().callFactory(new OkHttpClient.Builder().dispatcher(new Dispatcher().setMaxRequests(1).setMaxRequestsPerHost(1)).build()).build()`; I have definitely seen multiple enqueued requests complete out of order.

Comment: I have a doubt. Can i use call.cancel() instead of that?