# "Already executed" error (Retrofit2 and Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments, retrofit, retrofit2, android-fragmentactivity

First of all, I have 2 fragments and they show different json values(2 links). If I change fragment(.replace()), that fragment get values with retrofit and show it. It works well but other fragment is deleted with values. After change fragment, it downloads again so I change structure. I want to take 2 json objects once so I get json objects in mainactivity and fragments get these with methods. They work well in first opening but if i open a fragment second time, it gives this error. How can I solve it?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already executed.
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.enqueue(OkHttpCall.java:84)
```

Code is very long, i will show main structure.

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Call<Restaurant[]> restaurantCall;
    private Call<Dining[]> diningCall;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Restaurant Json value
        RestaurantInterface restaurantInterface = RetroClient.getClient().create(RestaurantInterface.class);
        restaurantCall = restaurantInterface.getJsonValues();

        //Dininghall Json value
        DiningInterface diningInterface = RetroClient.getClient().create(DiningInterface.class);
        diningCall = diningInterface.getJsonValues();
    }
    public Call<Restaurant[]> RestaurantJson()
    {
        return this.restaurantCall;
    }

    public Call<Dining[]> DiningJson()
    {
        return this.diningCall;
    }
}
```

> RestaurantFragment.java (Other fragment has same structure)

```
public class RestFragment extends Fragment
{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rest, container, false);

        Call<Restaurant[]> call = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).RestaurantJson();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Restaurant[]>()
        {
            .
            .
```

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35094488/3172725. You cannot use the same call twice, you need to clone your call.

Comment: I checked it but how can I use clone() for this?

Comment: `Call<Restaurant[]> retryCall = call.clone();`
`retryCall.enqueue(new Callback<Restaurant[]>()`... or `public Call<Restaurant[]> RestaurantJson() { return this.restaurantCall.clone(); }`

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I did return this.restaurantCall.clone(); and return this.diningCall.clone(); However, I thought it will download json objects in main activity but it download them in fragments. Why and what is the solution?

Comment: I replied with an answer to this new question for convenience...it was too long for a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summing up, in order to avoid the "Already executed" exception, clone the call:

```
public Call<Restaurant[]> RestaurantJson()
{
    return this.restaurantCall.clone();
}

public Call<Dining[]> DiningJson()
{
    return this.diningCall.clone();
}
```

If you want to execute the call in the activity and not in the fragment as you are actually doing, then you need to call `enqueue(new Callbak(...` in your activity.
So you need something like this:

```
public class RestFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rest, container, false);

        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).RestaurantJson(this);
    }

     public void onResponse(Response<T> response) {
         //your fragment code on response
     } 
    ...
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void RestaurantJson(final RestFragment fragment)
    {
        RestaurantInterface restaurantInterface = RetroClient.getClient().create(RestaurantInterface.class);
        restaurantCall = restaurantInterface.getJsonValues();
        restaurantCall.enqueue(new Callback<Restaurant[]>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
            ...
            fragment.onResponse(response);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The same for your DiningFragment and your dining call...

Comment: Thank you. First part works well. I will try second part later.